# error fetch array

Tags: php, html, mysql, fetch

I tried to fetch my all data using mysql_fetch_array with this code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row_counter % 2){
        $row_color="bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";
    }else{
        $row_color="bgcolor='#F3F6F8'";
    }
    echo "<tr class=\"TrColor\" ".$row_color.">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['applicant1_addr1'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_state'] . "</td>\n"; 
    echo "<td>$" . $row['invention-title'] . "</td>\n";  
    echo "</tr>";
    $row_counter++;
}
```

but I got an error

```
syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE, expecting ',' or ';'
```

in this line

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

anyone know what is wrong with that line?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line before `while` loop is not having a semi-colon `;` at the end

```
echo 'Whatever' //<--- You must be missing a semi-colon here
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ //<----- So not exactly this line, but the line before
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're missing a `;` or `,` on the line before that one.